# Django URL not loading response in browser, when opened from HTML file using href attribute

Tags: html, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I am comparatively new to web development , trying to open Django URL by "href" link in HTML file.
But URL response not loading fully in browser. While same link(URL), when opened directly in browser, url response loads fully.

Below is the sample Django view

```
def sampleview(request):
    return HttpResponse("URL response loaded fully")
```

Sample URL for view

```
url(r'^sampleurl/$', views.sampleview, name='sampleurl')
```

When opening URL link directly in browser

Browser shows the response as "URL response loaded fully"

While when opening the link through href attributes of html view,
like

```
<a href="/sampleurl">Sample link</a></li>
```

browser do not loads the response

Have tried following:

```
i) Making the link as  `href="/sampleurl/" instead of href="/sampleurl"`

ii)Using url name in the `{% url 'sampleurl' %} instead of  href="/sampleurl"`
```

but failed to resolve the issue

Comment: Have you tried `{% url '<app>:sampleurl' %}`, where `<app>` is the name of the app where you have the url configured?

Comment: Yes tried @Scratch'N'Purr

Comment: Is this HTML file a template file and rendered via django's template-view renderer or is it an external HTML file?

Comment: It's a template file and rendered via Django's template-view renderer